# R devtools check win functions throw Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = h) : Recv failure: Connection was reset

Tags: r, devtools, cran

In the process of submitting a package to CRAN I'm trying to run `check_win_devel()` and `check_win_release()` from devtools; both throw the error outlined above. Tried both with rstudio on windows and rstudio-server on wsl. After extensive Googling I haven't been able to find a workaround; I'm pretty clueless at this stage. Anyone came across the issue yet?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those two `devtools` functions submit your package to an external machine at win-builder.r-project.org for testing.  It looks as though that machine isn't allowing connections to receive your submission (maybe it's offline for the holiday break) or during tests your submission is trying to connect somewhere else, and that's failing.

I'd recommend following the instructions on win-builder.r-project.org for submitting your package instead of relying on `devtools` functions to do it.  Then you'll see the errors first hand if it's a submission problem.

Comment: CRAN folks on a break it seems indeed; may as well have switched off the lights. Thanks for helping.